# Unable to log in mysql server (docker) from asp.net (docker) compose

Tags: mysql, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, entity-framework-core

I have a docker compose file, which composes two docker instances:

- mysql server
- my asp.net app

The app connects to the mysql server with the following connection string:

```
"Server=db;Database=projects;User=dbUser;Password=dbPassword"
```

When I do that, the connection is rejected with the following error:

```
web_1  | Unhandled exception. MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Access denied for user 'dbUser'@'%' to database 'projects'
```

Note the weird '%' in the error message. I don't know if that's some hidden information that might reveal the actual root cause.

When I change my connection string to use root/root, everything works fine.

```
"Server=db;Database=projects;User=root;Password=root"
```

I am using the following docker compose file

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: projects
      MYSQL_USER: dbUser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: dbPassword
    ports:
    - 3306:3306
    expose:
      - 3306
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
  web:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    depends_on:
      - db
    build: 
      context: sb.projects.admin.app/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8001:80"

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

For reference, the SDK style project

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
        <RootNamespace>WebApplication3</RootNamespace>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="..\.dockerignore">
        <Link>.dockerignore</Link>
      </Content>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="[7.0.0]" />
      <PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="[8.0.0]" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="[7.0.4]" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.4" />
      <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="[7.0.0]" />
      <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen" Version="[6.5.0]" />
      <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI" Version="[6.5.0]" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Make sure mysql isn't running on the host also at that port.

Comment: I say that because the `%` can mean localhost. So the root connection that works, might actually be connecting to the wrong server instance.

Comment: Nah there is no Mysql server running on my host. But at least the % sign is explained